# isinstance in Jython

Tags: list, class, jython, isinstance

In CPython, you can check if something is, for example, a `list`, using `isinstance(something, list)`.

This same code doesn't work in Jython, though. In Jython, it throws this exception: `TypeError: isinstance(): 2nd arg is not a class`.

Comment: Which version of Jython are you using?  I just tried 2.7b2 and 2.7b4 and they worked as expected.

Comment: @DavidCharles: I'm using the version that comes with WAS 8.5, which is quite dated. Version 2.1. Is `list` a `class` in your version? I wonder if `list` was a `function` in Python 2.1. Either way, I run these scripts under Python 2.6 and Jython 2.1, so I need them to written so that they run in both.

Comment: To answer your question: On jython2.7b2, `list.__class__` prints `<type 'type'>`, which is exactly what python2.7.6 says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Jython, `list` is a `function`, not a `class`. You can find this out by running: `list.__class__`, which will print `<jclass org.python.core.BuiltinFunctions at ...>` in contrast to Python which will print out `<type 'list'>` given the same code.

I found two ways to make this work.

1. Use `isinstance(something, [].__class__)`.
2. If you run `[].__class__` in Jython, it'll print out `<jclass org.python.core.PyList at ...>`. So you could do `import org` and then `isinstance(something, org.python.core.PyList)`.

Neither option looks all that great. The second one is probably easier to understand, but has the disadvantage of only working on Jython, whereas the first one works equally well on both runtimes.